# iPhone LED / Flash light on charging?

Tags: ios, iphone, charging

I just recently bought an iphone this year, and need to know if it has any led flash light for letting my know that it's charging?

I have iPhone 5c, and it's got this setting for light for call and message alerts. I'm trying to look for a similar setting for when it's in charging mode.

Please could someone provide any help regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly there is no led light for when it is charging it only vibrates/shows a picture of a battery

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I thought there might be some app allowing this feature, maybe it's not supported even via apps...?

Answer (score 1):

Best you can do is to tap the Home button.

Green Battery level, top right, & briefly a charge percentage under the current time are your easiest indicators.

When you first plug it in a double-buzz or a *'mim'* sound is your clue it recognised the charger & is now charging.